# start a service from device browser

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have 2 application, a web app and an android app. I need tor start a service in my android application by pressing a button in the web application and send some data to it.
is it possible?

Comment: Did you try with sending push notification from web server to android app on button pressed of web page ? If  you can do that then on notification receive you can start service

Comment: @Afsaredrisy Well it's a little bit complicated, both android and web app must operate offline with localhost. so, no online services allowed.

Comment: So in that case holding a web-socket connection from android app with localhost server is one solution.

Comment: @Afsaredrisy in this way, android should call the web or web should call the android. I want my web app call android app and also send data to it.

Comment: With web socket, you can hold an always alive connection from android to web app and when button is pressed then web app (Running on localhost) can send data to android app via web socket connection.